# PyPy 2.2.1 and SQLAlchemy/Storm

Tags: sqlalchemy, pypy, storm-orm

We are starting a project that uses PyPy 2.2.1 and we want to start using SQLAlchemy in it. One thing we noticed is that when installing SQLAlchemy in the pypy virtual environment the following message appeared:

> WARNING: C extensions are not supported on this Python platform, speedups are not enabled.

We, of course are concerned by the performance of the SQL queries that we will build and the manipulation of the result sets; and we don't really know how high can be the magnitude of these speedups not being enabled in SQLAlchemy. In addition, while we were looking into other solutions, for the sake of a test, installing Storm and SQLObject didn't throw any warning message like SQLAlchemy did in the pypy virtual environment.

In this specific scenario, would you recomend to still use SQLAlchemy even if the speedups are not enabled? or using an ORM like Storm would have better performance specially when dealing with complex queries and larger result sets?

Answer (score 1):

the C Extensions in sqlalchemy provide a faster result set object than can be easily achieved in pure python, but you may get good benefits in this case from the pypy jit.  Even if you don't, this won't in any way affect query performance.  The warning can be safely ignored.